# Where can I find the Ubuntu wiki theme?

Tags: repository, mediawiki

Does anyone know where I can get hold of the source code to Ubuntu's current mediawiki theme, 'light'? There don't appear to be any links under the artwork and themes section of the wiki itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theme can be found [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-website-community/ubuntu-website/light-wiki/files). I found it ducking for **ubuntu moinmoin** *(the wiki engine [wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HelpContents) uses)* **theme**.

Comment: Lol ducking=duck duck go?

Comment: Ah, I thought they where using Mediawiki. Goes to show how much the UI of both have converged! Still, useful.

Comment: Don't discount MoinMoin.  The best feature that MoinMoin has built-in is intuitive and secure access control lists.  Trying to add permissions (security) to Mediawiki is, at best, a hack.